# Netbeans, Distributed Jar file, Increasing Heap Size

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm, heap-memory

I am building an application with NetBeans and I need to increase the heap-size. I am modifying running parameters from Netbeans but I have no idea to modify the heap-size in the .jar file. How can I achieve this?

I mean how to include it embedded to the jar file, not by using another runner script (.bat for windows or .sh for linux)

Comment: Are you building an application based on the NetBeans platform?

Comment: Java 5.0+ gives the JVM 1/4 of the main memory of the system by default, you may not have to increase or decrease it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no sir, just using netbeans to produce my software.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Lawrey but this is ridicolous, what if I want to use 1/2 of my 512 GB memory in a server, makes a huge difference.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest you use more than one memory band for a Java process. Most servers have 4 memory bands in a 512 MB server. A heap of larger than 16 GB isn't a good idea most of the time as the full GC cost is very high. If you have an exceptional case where you want lots of memory, you can afford to have a batch script (or you can have the process restart itself with more memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify it when you launch you software from the jar. Use the -Xmx option on Linux, for instance.